# DO loops and data input in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the university edition of SAS.
I have data from treatment groups A, B, and C. I am trying to use DO loops to process the groups separately for comparison. I can do it in one nested DO loop when the data lengths are the same. But these groups have different numbers of observations and I am running into trouble. Here is my code:

```
data AirPoll1 (keep = Group Ozone);
label Group = "Treatment Group";
label Ozone = 'Ozone level (in ppb)';
do i=1 to 1;
input Group $@@
do j=1 to 15;
    input Ozone @@;
    output;
    end;
end;
do i=1 to 1;
input Group $ @@;
do j=1 to 10;
    input Ozone @@;
    output;
    end;
end;
do i=1 to 1;
input Group $ @@;
do j=1 to 11;
    input Ozone @@;
    output;
    end;
end;

datalines;
A 4 6 3 4 7 8 2 3 4 1 8 9 5 6 3
B 5 3 6 2 1 2 4 3 2 4
C 8 9 7 8 6 7 6 7 9 8 9
;
run;
proc univariate data = AirPoll1;
Var Ozone;
by Group;
histogram Ozone;
run;
```

The error I am getting is:

> ERROR 161-185: No matching DO/SELECT statement.

Is there a quick way to fix this?

Comment: you just missed a ; after input Group $@@ after your first do loop `do i=1 to 1;
input Group $@@**;**`

Comment: @kl78 That would do it! Not sure how I missed it, but I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix indeed

you have missed off the semi-colon of the first input line,

doh:)

happy programming